# I cannot run uiautomatorviewer on my macbook M1

Tags: appium, uiautomatorviewer

**Machine**
macBook Air M1

**OS**
macOS Big Sur Version 11.5.2

**java -version**

java version "1.8.0_301"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode)

**bash_profile**

```
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib
   export MAVEN_HOME=/Users/XXX/Documents/apache-maven-3.8.2
   export M2=$MAVEN_HOME/bin
   export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/XXX/Library/Android/sdk
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/x86_64
```

On running uiautomatorviewer on terminal i get below exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashFormLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashFormLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeChildSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runSettings(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:78)
```

Please let me know if anyone was able experience a similar issue and has a solution.

Thanks,
Nahid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a better alternative than uiautomator - appium inspector.

If you have installed appium GUI on your mac follow below steps:

1. Start appium server
2. Click the search button to start the appium inspector
   [image]
3. Provide below your android configurations
   {
   "platformName":   "Android",
   "platformVersion":   "8.1", //<>
   "app":   "/path/to/.apk/file",
   "deviceName":   "c33143r", //<<get device name using: $ adb devices>>
   "automationName":   "UiAutomator2"
   }

Comment: what's ur jdk version @Nahid

Answer (score 1):

I had the below configurations and Java version is 1.8.0_332

```
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$PATH
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_SDK 
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$HOME/.android/and
alias emulator='$ANDROID_SDK/emulator/emulator'
```

In my case, the below solution worked like a charm

https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/911#issuecomment-849389068

1. Download the swt.jar, from [https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/911#issuecomment-849389068), rename downloaded ***swt.jar*** to ***swt2.jar***
2. copy ***swt2.jar*** to *Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64/* [Note: DO NOT REPLACE/DELETE]
3. Launch uiautomatorviewer